# make divs align in rows

Tags: html, css

I am working on a search system and when i search something i want everything to align in rows

Before i search:
After i search:
The jquery/javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var $search = $("#search").on('input',function(){
        $btns.removeClass('active');
        var matcher = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'gi');
        $('.box').show().not(function(){
            return matcher.test($(this).find('.name, .sku').text())
        }).hide();
    })
})
```

Html and css:

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search product by name or sku">
        </div>

<a id="recept1-anchor" href="chiligryta.html" >
<div id="recept1" class="box">
  <img src="bild/recept1-bild.jpg" height="400" style="max-width: 300px">
  <div style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9); position:absolute;  width:300px; height:100px; top:300px; font-size:35px; text-align:center;color: black;outline:none; text-decoration:none;" >
      <p class="name">Chiligryta</p>
    </div>
</div>
</a>

<a id="recept2-anchor" href="chiligryta.html" >
<div id="recept2" class="box">
  <img src="bild/recept1-bild.jpg" height="400" style="max-width: 300px">
  <div style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9); position:absolute;  width:300px; height:100px; top:300px; font-size:35px; text-align:center;color: black;outline:none; text-decoration:none;" >
    <p class="name">Snake</p>

    </div>

</div>
</a>
```

Like i said i expect the divs to just line up pretty when i search

Comment: Welcome to SO, please look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You will need to provide some more info so we know what you want the result to be like; as well as maybe the code actually replicating your issue

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd recommend wrapping each receipt entirely inside of a `<div>` instead of having content that renders outside of it. To render a group of `<div>` tags into a row:

```css
.inline-div { 
  width: 200px; /* Or whatever you'd like the width to be */
  height: auto; /* So that you dont have to worry about content being hidden */
  display: inline-block; /* Brings all the divs into the same line, unless they go past the container in which case they'll wrap */
  vertical-align: top; /* Aligns each div to the tops of each container */ 
}
```

Add the class `.inline-div` to each div to apply the styles to them.

Comment: OP's using Bootstrap, modifying those classes is not recommended

Comment: I'd say it still not a really good idea; `row` already has a `display: flex` property that might cause issues when overriding it with `display: inline-block`... I think OP really needs to provide more info on whats happening at the moment to approach the issue efficiently

Comment: I'm just offering a solution which does not include bootstrap, which I personally do not ever use. There does need to be more information given though.

Answer (score -2):

You need to be clear about your desired result.

If you display all `<div/>`'s that you want to display in a `<div/>` having class row and make sure that the inner `<div/>`'s width is small enough so that other `<div/>`'s can fit in a row and use display `inline-block` property.
**OR**
You may also use `.col-md-2` for each div so that you can display at least 6 `<div/>` in a row.